# Breaking up long running function with setTimeout to allow event handling

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I have to find a way to implement a function which takes an input number and returns/displays the closest lesser prime number or the input itself if it's a prime.

However, the input can be a very large number and in this case the inner function blocks the event loop and I have to make sure about that the browser would be able to handle events during the calculation.

My implementation looks like this:

```
function getClosestPrime(num) {
    return isPrime(num) ? num : getClosestPrime(num-1);
}

function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
    }
  return num !== 1;
}
```

Can someone please help me with the implementation and give me an explanation/hints for future reference, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the prime number, use this [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Generate once for maximum number possible and use it afterward without calculating. anaing and again for all numbers

Comment: Also, for a really easy optimization, you only need to check numbers up to `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num))` when checking divisors. That will cut out well more than half of the iterations.

Comment: You probably need a web worker to run it in another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JavaScript is single threaded the best solution would be to get a second thread to solve the problem for you. This can be achieved by using the [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

With a web worker in place your client side algorithm is simply:

- Create a worker.
- Send it a message when we you want it to calculate the prime.
- Listen for a message called 'done', this indicates that the worker has finished.

Client-side code:

```
// create the worker
var primeWorker = new Worker('calculate-prime.js');

function doPrimeComputationInWorker(number) {

  function handleWorkerCompletion(message) {
    if (message.data.command == 'done') {
      // update UI using the 'primeNumber' value received in the message 
      console.log(message.data.primeNumber);
      // remove the event listener
      primeWorker.removeEventListener('message', handleWorkerCompletion);
    }
  }

  // add the event listener
  primeWorker.addEventListener('message', handleWorkerCompletion, false);

  // post the number to the worker
  primeWorker.postMessage({
    'number': number
  });
}
```

The code should be simple enough for you to follow, all you have to do is change the code for updating the UI when the worker completes.

Now you need the web worker code. Here's a skeleton for `calculate-prime.js`:

```
// add the event listener
self.addEventListener('message', start);

function start(message) {
  // get the number value from the message
  var number = message.data.number;

  // perform the calculation
  var nearestPrime = calculateNearestPrime(number);

  // return the result
  self.postMessage({
    'command': 'done',
    'primeNumber': nearestPrime
  });
}

function calculateNearestPrime(number) {
  // your implementation goes here
  // return the result
  return result;
}
```

I'll leave the calculation of the prime numbers up to you but the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is quite easy to implement and you will find JavaScript implementations online if you don't want to write the code yourself. You could use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to save a list of generated prime numbers and speed up future calculations.

For future reference you should learn about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) so that you can use them for resolving your asynchronous problems.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the detailed explanation. I was not familiar with workers yet so this is a great opportunity to practice and learn about them.

Comment: Web Workers are very good for offloading work from the UI thread. Just don't create too many (100+) of them because each one is a new thread for the processor. I fixed up the code sample, in the `handleWorkerCompletion` function `worker` should have been `primeWorker`.

Answer (score 1):

How about use setTimeout inside Promise.

```
function getClosestPrime(num) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (isPrime(num)) {
      resolve(num);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(getClosestPrime(num-1)), 0);
    }
  })
}

function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return num !== 1;
}

setTimeout(() => alert("foo"), 0);     // 1st alerted
getClosestPrime(10000000).then(alert); // 3rd
setTimeout(() => alert("bar"), 0);     // 2nd
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it works well and doesn't block event handling when setTimout's callback is not fired immediately, but with a little delay (~1000ms).